# How to display a print progress dialog in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, printing, progress-bar

If I do this in my class that implements Printable,

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setJobName( /* some name */ );
Book book = new Book();
book.append(this, new PageFormat());
job.setPageable(book);
boolean ok = job.printDialog();
if (ok) {
    try {
        job.print();
    } 
    catch (PrinterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

it works, but my Printable class gets `print()` called twice. (presumably for resource allocation purposes by the printer driver)

How can I display a progress bar properly? In my case, I know how many sub-printing tasks need to execute, but if I try to display it, the progress bar will proceed from start to finish twice, which is horrible feedback for a user. And I'd rather not display an indeterminate progress bar....

What should I do?

---

clarification: I'm printing a bunch of plots on a page. They're somewhat intricate and take a while to print, so I might know that there's 10 objects to render, so I'd like to have my progress bar go from 0 to 10, and increment it after I render each of the 10 objects. (Or, even better, go from 0 to 20, assuming I could somehow know the page was being rendered twice.)

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html and http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm

Comment: do you understand that this dialog will output the process of converting you printable into printer internal format, and not the actual printing (which is handled by the system)?

Comment: @Penkov: yes, because the actual printing handled by the system gives feedback in other ways depending on the printer driver. My page takes 1-3 seconds for printing and the reason I'm wanting a dialog is because I need to give some kind of feedback that my program is doing something.

Comment: @mKorbel: Please read the question again. I know how to print. I know how to display a progress bar.  What I don't know is how to display a progress bar that advances from start to completion along with the print rendering, because `print()` is called twice.

Comment: hmm ... just to understand the "from start to finish twice": the printable is called with pageIndex (0 ... n) and then again (0 ... n)? This potentially wrecks my typical strategy, as what I have seen so far is (0..0) (1..1) ... (n..n) with the obvious solution ;-) darn ..

Comment: reading again, I don't quite understand the nature of your "sub-printing tasks" ... finer-grained than once-per-page?

Comment: @kleopatra: good point, adding a note in my problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on the idea of trying to predict or distinguish the # of calls to print().

@Atreys' answer was promising, but the only difference that I could use w/o reflection or importing private `sun.*` classes was that `sun.print.PeekGraphics` implements `java.awt.image.ImageObserver`, whereas `sun.awt.windows.WPathGraphics` does not. (getClass().getName() counts as reflection in my book)

What I ended up doing was to use my progress bar for each individual call to `Printable.print()`, e.g. reset the progress to the beginning and advance it for each substep of print.

To keep the users from complaining that the progress bar shows progress twice, I have a label that is changed to "Pass #{k}" whenever print() is called, where {k} is a counter that is incremented each time.

---

p.s. The proper way to cancel a print job from within `Printable.print()` is a little tricky. Throwing PrintAbortException doesn't seem to work correctly, as it ends the call to print() but the printer driver keeps going, despite the fact that the [`Printable` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html) says this:

> If the Printable object aborts the print job then it throws a PrinterException.

Instead, you have to cast the print() method's Graphics parameter as a PrintGraphics object, and then call PrintGraphics.getPrinterJob().cancel():

```
if (graphics instanceof PrinterGraphics)
{
    PrinterGraphics pg = (PrinterGraphics) graphics;
    pg.getPrinterJob().cancel();
}
else
{
    // this is kind of an unexpected circumstance
    // not sure if we should do this or throw IllegalStateException()
    PrinterAbortException pae = new PrinterAbortException();
    pae.initCause(/* something */);
    throw pae;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the arguments supplied to the print method, the first time it's called (for me at least), the graphics is a PeekGraphics object, and the second time is a WPathGraphics one. On my system, [`RasterPrinterJob`](http://www.j6a.ru/_raster_printer_job_8java_source.html) is creating a PeekGraphics to get information about the print job before setting up the graphics for the real print job.

Depending on how you're updating your progress bar, you might be able to just check that the graphics argument is not a PeekGraphics before you give it a tick.